# AngularFireAuth UI Flicker on AngularFireSeed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularfire

I've been struggling with the fact that when you refresh the account page on AngularFireSeed the login screen flashes and then it redirects to account page. I'm also noticing ng-hide isn't working to hide the login link which flashes before angular realizes its authenticated and shows logout link.

I found a proposed solution in the link below, but I tried for a few hours and couldn't get it to work. I think because there are details that are missing: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-angular/bO0AW2V9d9w

Any idea what I can do to fix this. Trying not to have to hack angularFire or write code in the vanilla Firebase API, but its looking like it might come to that.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to manually initialize AngularJS as pointed out on the mailing list. Does that help with the flicker?

Comment: I haven't been able to get it to work. But its also not the direction I wanted to take. I was hoping to use angularFireAuth.initalize as provided in AngularFireSeed. If I did it the way he suggests I would have to not use a lot of the convenience methods you guys provided in angularFire. Right? Is his way the only way?

Comment: No, the flicker is just due to initialize *Angular* itself, it has no impact on whether you can use AngularFire or not.